# How to increase the font size of the math mode when I declare my custom font size

Tags: fonts, titles, fontsize

I declared custom font size at 45pt via the command

```
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 45pt
```

I'm writing an article with title in the first page. I want my title font size to be 45pt as defined above. So, I wrote in the preamble:

```
\title{ \textsc{ \textbf{\myfont Modules All Of Whose Right Submodules Are $C4$- 
       Modules}} }
```

Everything works fine except that the $C4$, the part written in math mode is too smaller in font size that other letters in the title. How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should not use `\font` in latex, that is a low level font command that cuts out all of the latex font machinary so the math will not see the size change and your `\textsc` and `\textbf` commands are doing nothing useful as `\myfont` will ignore them and use medium weight roman

Comment: It is good practice to avoid _all_ formatting commands in `\title` (the formatting should be specified in the `\maketitle` setup) but for a one-off title forced to 45pt use `\fontsize{45pt}{50pt}\selectfont`

Comment: Can you provide please the full code of the \title and \maketitle after your modifications?. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use `\font` in latex, that is a low level font command that cuts out all of the latex font machinery so the math will not see the size change and your `\textsc` and `\textbf` commands are doing nothing useful as `\myfont` will ignore them and use medium weight roman

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {
% old \LARGE
\scshape\bfseries\fontsize{45pt}{48pt}\selectfont 
\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Wrong}

\font\myfont=cmr12 at 45pt

Not bold, not small caps, not T1 encoded and math wrong size. Set on the wrong linespacing

\textsc{\textbf{\myfont Modules All Of Whose Right Submodules Are $C4$-Modules}}

\clearpage
\section*{Less Wrong}


Not bold 45pt small caps,  T1 encoded  and math.set on 48pt line spacing

{\fontsize{45pt}{48pt}\selectfont\textsc{\textbf{ Modules All Of Whose Right Submodules Are $C4$-Modules}}\par}

\clearpage
\section*{More right}

Formatting separated from the document markup.

\title{Modules All Of Whose Right Submodules Are $C4$-Modules}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but the title is not centered in the page!!

Comment: @HusseinEid the title is centred in the last example so I don't understand your comment. If you mean you don't want it centred start from your current definition and just add the font. I started from the definition in article class as you had given no example or information.

Comment: I mean that I want the title to be centered vertically. Indeed, the title is centered horizontally. I'm using article class as well. I apologize if I disturb you.

Comment: @HusseinEid well that is a completely different question than the one you asked, as your original code would not have made a vertically centered title. However put `\vspace*{\fill}` at the start and  end of the definition of the title.

Comment: Thanks alot David ♥ .

Comment: One final question (I promise). Is it possible to increase the spacing between the lines of the title abit ?

Comment: @HusseinEid the line spacing isthe second parameter of `\fontsize` so try `{45pt}{55pt}`